# PayPal Event Notification, type: "Withdraw Funds to Bank Account" (Does it exist?)

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-pdt, paypal-webhooks

I am trying to handle transactions generated from PayPal bank withdrawals.

Bank withdrawals occur when the system (via automatic transfers) or the user transfers funds from the PayPal Account to a connected bank account.  This creates the transaction type: "Withdraw Funds to Bank Accounts"

Will any of the PayPal Notification systems send the details of these transaction types when they occur?  All event notifications I can find revolve around sales (charges, authorizations, refunds, ect.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are no IPNs triggered when you withdrawal funds from PayPal to the bank, however, the TransactionSearch API does include those (I think).

You'll want to double check it, but if I remember correctly you would see them there.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Webhooks does not support an event for "Withdraw funds to Bank Accounts". You may have a look at the supported Webhook Events @ https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/#event-types

Also, IPN does not support this event. Pls refer to developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/ for more details across PayPal IPN.

You may suggest support for this event notification at https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/My-Feedback-for-PayPal/bd-p/CA-Feedback